# The letter gets into the spam folder in google mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

When users register, some emails get into the spam folder.

I have two functions:
The first will make a configuration for nodemailer.

```
function sendingLetter() {
    return nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: config.transport.service,
        secure: config.transport.ssl,
        auth: {
            user: config.transport.user,
            pass: config.transport.password
        }
    });
}
```

The second is making a template for sending by mail with a link

```
function statusCheck(file, replacements) {
    let html_file = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    let template = handlebars.compile(html_file);
    let htmlToSend = template(replacements);
    return htmlToSend;
}
```

The function of sending letters to the user's mail

```
const smtpTransport = sendingLetter();
const confirm_email = path.join(__dirname, '../views/email_templates/users/confirm_email.html');

...

let rand_hash = Date.now();
let link = 'https://' + config.kHostName + '/api/users/verify/' + rand_hash;
let replacements = {
   target_link: link,
};
let htmlToSend = statusCheck(confirm_email, replacements);
let mailOptions = {
   from: config.transport.user,
   to: user_email,
   subject: Constants.users.messages.subjectConfimEmail,
   html: htmlToSend,
};
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

The template in which the link will be inserted to be sent to the user by mail

```
<p>
    We're ready to activate your account. All we need to do is make sure this is your email address.
</p>    
<a href="{{target_link}}"
    <div class="butten">
        Confirm Email
    </div>      
</a>
```

In some cases, Google sends my email to a spam folder. Why it happens? What are some tips to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an algorithm within Google to categorize the messages according to your interest and have probably been categorized as undesirable.

The classification of messages sent from any website as spam is one of the most important things that a webmaster should pay attention to. I will discuss in this article what things a webmaster should pay attention to to ensure that messages sent by him Its website as spam (spam) ends up in a non-spam folder or spam folder.

## How do service providers classify messages as spam?

The e-mail service providers use many methods and tools to filter the incoming e-mails of the system and accordingly decide whether or not the message should be classified as an annoying message.

Content-based filtering "Content Filters"

Filter based on the letterhead of the email "Email Header Filters"

Filter based on blacklists "Blacklist Filters"

Filter based on user decision "User Rule-based filters"

## Methods of Solution

## First: Filter based on Content Content Filters

Through which the content of the message and the method of writing it to find out whether the message is disturbing or not, by comparing the content to a database containing a set of words used in the spam and certainly every service provider has his own words in this area called " Spam Trigger Words, "and there are many lists of English words that can be found using the previous search term in the Google search engine.
Also, the service providers, through this mechanism, search the way in which the message was written, especially if the HTML code was used to write the message, then the service provider makes sure that the code written is a clean code.
The following are some tips that can be provided to avoid placing your message as spam based on the filtering mechanism based on the content:

Make sure that the title of the subject is not too long and not so short that it is just one word.

Make sure that the title or text of the message is not fully capitalized when writing in English.

Make sure that the message title does not contain Re: unless the message is actually in response to a message sent by the recipient.

Do not use a question mark in the message title.

You can use the $ $ sign in a sequential address or message content, for example, $$$.

When you write a message in HTML, do not use video, JavaScript or JavaScript in the message, and make sure that the HTML code is clean, standard and written correctly according to HTML standards.

## Second: Liquidation Based on the letterhead "Email Header Filters":

Through this mechanism the server receives the message of the search for any false data can be found in the letterhead and accordingly classified as an annoying message or not.

## Third: Liquidation based on blacklists "Blacklist Filters":

Blacklists are constantly updated databases that contain a list of IP addresses for servers that are based on or send spam messages.

## Fourth: Liquidation based on the user's decision "User Rule-based filters":

Although this mechanism is not of great importance because it depends on the decision of the recipient of the message itself, but it must be mentioned, and in this mechanism the recipient of the message itself to indicate the message received as an annoying message and therefore in the following times to be written by the same address The message will go to the spam folder directly.

In the end I apologize for my relatively weak English.